# Re-Arranging icons inside application

Tags: android

I would like to know how to implement arranging of icons inside the application menu in android?
I can quote the example of Car view app in Nexus S, where we can move the icons after touching the icon for a while and then moving it. Similar to that in samsung android phones, where we can move the icons at our ease on the home screen.
Any thoughts/suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the drag and drop functionality described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: Drag/Drop listener are available after api 11. For previous version, is there any solutions?

Comment: You could attach a View.OnTouchListener() to your screen, and then do math to calculate and draw the icon as a the finger moves across the screen. Pretty hacky. You could also look in the source to see how the home screen launcher is implemented.